# Error trying to access native method

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde, native-methods

Am developing a BlackBerry app and I have a third party JAR file which i make it as library and i am extending it in my application.
The problem is when I try to access to some method of that library, the simulator gives me the error net.rim.vm.MissingNativeError, and the console shows: JVM: Missing Native Method.
I had previously load the .cod file with the library in my simulator, but it doesn't work.

Please help me with this, I have dealing with it almost a week!

Thanks a lot for your answers.

BTW i'm working with JDE 5.0.

Comment: Which 3rd party library are you using? Does it give details on which method is giving the error? Is it all methods? More details would really help us.

Comment: @Swati Is a private library. In all its methods.

Comment: Try changing the project type to a CLDC application instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to native methods using Java on BlackBerry OS.

The only APIS you can access are those defined in the documentation.

For the avoidance of doubt, this is for BB7 phones and earlier. There is no Java on BB10.